# Flask + Jinja2: how to replace the occurrence of a value in a table by a icon

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, pandas

I am working on a simple web page showing the content of a pandas `DataFrame` by using the Flask framework:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import DatabaseConnector
from jinja2 import Environment

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_options = {'lstrip_blocks': True, 'trim_blocks': True}
app.create_jinja_environment()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    connector = DatabaseConnector()
    df = connector.getAvailableData()
    return render_template('index.html', tables=[df.to_html(classes='data', header=True)])
```

From a tutorial I borrowed the following jinja/html code in a file `index.html` extending `base.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{% block title %}Status Viewer{% endblock %}</h1>
    {% for table in tables %}
            {{ table|safe }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The result it produces is somewhat OK:

[image: Resulting table on web page]

Now I would like to make the table a bit mor fancy and replace the True/False status in the columns "Collecting"/"Archiving" with a red/green dot or tick mark icon. How can I do that?

I suppose there is more than one approach to this problem, in this sense I don't care if the solution is in CSS, JavaScript, Jinja2, Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas `to_html()` method `formatter` options.
Please refer this official documentation:
[pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html)

**OR**

You can also use pandas styler option.
Please refer this documentation:
[Panda dataframe table style guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

Also just for example, you can get idea from below snippet:
**NOTE:** This below snippet is just for example.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    connector = DatabaseConnector()
    df = connector.getAvailableData()
    df.style.apply(
    lambda x: ['font-weight: bold; background-color: yellow'
               if your_df_column_name == your_condition_true_false else '' for your_df_column_name in x])
    return render_template('index.html', tables=[df.to_html(classes='data', header=True)])
```